# ForEach文で中身の処理中に母集合側が変化するとMoveNextでエラーになる？

Tags: c#, unity3d, .net

下記コードのForEachを使った処理で①~④の処理中にDownLoadDataListのカウントが変化すると
次のMoveNextでエラーになるのでしょうか？

ループが１週した後に、ForEachまで来ると下記のエラーがでます。
**InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.**

```
foreach (DownLoadData downloaddata in DownLoadDataList)
{
    ①処理・・・・・・
    ②処理・・・・・・
    ③処理・・・・・・
    ④処理・・・・・・
}
```

DownLoadDataListはList＜DownLoadData＞で定義されています。

環境はUnity5.0.1f1 .Netは2.0です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

仕様上、foreachの処理中にコレクションに追加・削除が発生すると、**InvalidOperationException**が発生します。
正確には、GetEnumeratorメソッドがそのように実装されています。

これを回避する方法は、いくつかあります。
代表的なのが追加、削除、foreachなどの操作を行うとき、コレクション全体をlockする手法です。
しかし、デッドロックを引き起こす可能性があります。
lockの管理(排他制御)は、細心の注意を払わなければなりません。

第二の方法として**System.Collections.Concurrent**名前空間にあるコレクションを使用する手法です。
Concurrentなコレクションは、lock不要なコレクションです。
コレクションをforeachすると、そのコレクションのスナップショットを使用してforeachが行われます。
そのため、追加、削除が発生し、コレクションが変更されても、例外を発生しません。
しかし、Concurrent系のコレクションは、インデクサによるアクセスができません。

第三の方法として、nugetから追加が必要となりますが、
**System.Collections.Immutable**名前空間のコレクションを使用する手法です。
追加、削除などの操作は、新しいコレクションに反映され、元のコレクションに影響を与えません。
しかし、コレクション全体を複製するため、頻繁な変更が発生するとパフォーマンスに影響を与えることがあります。

Answer (score 5):

仕様通りの動作です。リストのバージョンが変わるとそれ以前に`List<T>.GetEnumerator()`の返した`IEnumerator`は無効になります。

要件に合わせて`List<T>.ToArray()`や`Enumerable.ToList()`でリストを複製するようにしてください。